# ASP NET Core 3 - Forgot Password 500 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP NET Core 3 project and I added Identity.  I haven't done anything with the Forgot Password page yet and tested it for the first time.  I received a 500 error and this error is confusing me.  Can you help me debug this?

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
      Connection ID "18158513729233223683", Request ID "80000006-0007-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'LFPortal.Services.EmailSender'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(PageContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateModelFactory>b__0(PageContext pageContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 92.0026ms 500
```

Here's the EmailSender class

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        // Our private configuration variables
        private string host;
        private int port;
        private bool enableSSL;
        private string userName;
        private string password;

        // Get our parameterized configuration
        public EmailSender(string host, int port, bool enableSSL, string userName, string password)
        {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.enableSSL = enableSSL;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password),
                EnableSsl = enableSSL
            };
            return client.SendMailAsync(
                new MailMessage(userName, email, subject, message) { IsBodyHtml = true }
            );
        }
    }
```

Here's the ConfigureServices section...

```
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>(i =>
                new EmailSender(
                    Configuration["EmailSender:Host"],
                    Configuration.GetValue<int>("EmailSender:Port"),
                    Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EmailSender:EnableSSL"),
                    Configuration["EmailSender:UserName"],
                    Configuration["EmailSender:Password"]
                )
            );
```

Comment: Maybe the EmailSender-class needs a string-Parameter in the constructor?

Comment: I added my EmailSender class

Comment: Can you also add the configureServices-Code, where you register your Email-Sender?

Comment: Added the ConfigureServices section

Comment: Maybe any value is missing in the Configuration? You could try to remove the parameters from the constructor, and submit the Configuration instead. Then throw your own exception, if any Value was missing there.

Comment: I stepped through and all of the values are coming through correctly.  I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the EmailSender main method and it never reaches it.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you check, if you did, what I wrote in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try:

For the EmailSender class

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    // Our private configuration variables
    private string host;
    private int port;
    private bool enableSSL;
    private string userName;
    private string password;

    // Get our parameterized configuration
    public EmailSender(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.host = config["EmailSender:Host"],
        this.port = config.GetValue<int>("EmailSender:Port"),
        this.enableSSL = config.GetValue<bool>("EmailSender:EnableSSL"),
        this.userName = config["EmailSender:UserName"],
        this.password = config["EmailSender:Password"]                                   

    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password),
            EnableSsl = enableSSL
        };
        return client.SendMailAsync(
            new MailMessage(userName, email, subject, message) { IsBodyHtml = true }
        );
    }
}
```

To give an explanation the EmailSender is registered as Transient...
For the ConfigureServices section...

```
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>(i =>
            new EmailSender(
                Configuration
            )
        );
```

And now put a breakpoint at the contructor.

If you want the EmailSender in an Controller let DI resolve it:

```
Public class ExampleController:Controller 
{
     // private field
    private IEmailSender sender;

     //Constructor with Parameter, Dependency Injection should do the rest 
    public ExampleController( IEmailSender eSender)
       {
            // set field
            sender = eSender;
       }

       //your Code,Methods,... where you can use the field.
 }
```

Comment: I didn't need the breakpoint because that fixed it!  Now, I need to initialize the EmailSender object from other pages, so how do I access the Configuration outside of Startup.cs?

Comment: I think that did it!  Thank you!